# How do I show that a polynomial equation has roots between a and b and that the root must be irrational

Tags: polynomials

> Consider the quadratic equation $x^5 + x = 10$. Show that the root of this equation is :
>
> a) the only real root,
>
> b) lies between $1$ and $2$, and
>
> c) is irrational

How do I show this? I am stuck and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: $1^5+1<10<2^5+2$.

Comment: (a) should be changed to 'the only **real** root'

Comment: Yeah sorry fixed that

Comment: I don't know where to begin this question

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

a) The derivative $5x^4+1$ is positive.

b) $f(1)=2, f(2)=34$.

c) By the rational root theorem, the only rational roots must be integer.